# Error in HTML string function when running on some server

Tags: c#, asp.net, somee

```
<div class="form-group">
    <span class="auto-style2">
            <label class="col-xs control-label">First Name:</label>
    </span>
    <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" value="<%:get_signUp_values()[0] %>" class="form-control" />
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <span class="auto-style2">
        <label class="col-xs control-label">Last Name:</label>
    </span>
    <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" value="<%:get_signUp_values()[1] %>" class="form-control" />
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <span class="auto-style2">
        <label class="col-xs control-label">Birthday:</label>
    </span>
    <input type="text" name="dob" id="dob" value="<%:get_signUp_values()[2] %>-<%:get_signUp_values()[3] %>-<%:get_signUp_values()[4] %>" class="form-control" />
</div>
```

this is the code which is giving error

`value="<%:get_signUp_values()[0] %>"`

This is giving an `IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.`. This error is occurring on somee, but not on `localhost`.

Code-behind:

```
public List<HtmlString> get_signUp_values()
{
    int userid = Convert.ToInt32(Session["USERID"]);

    List<DAO_SignUp> get_signUp_val = new List<DAO_SignUp>(DAO_SignUp.get_signUp(userid));

    List<HtmlString> get_values = new List<HtmlString>();

    foreach (var obj2 in get_signUp_val)
    {
        get_values.Add(new HtmlString(obj2.get_First_name));
        get_values.Add(new HtmlString(obj2.get_last_name));

        string dob = obj2.get_dob.ToString();
        string patren = "-";
        string[] substrings = Regex.Split(dob, patren);
        string day = substrings[0];
        string month = substrings[1];
        string year = substrings[2];

        get_values.Add(new HtmlString(day));
        get_values.Add(new HtmlString(month));
        get_values.Add(new HtmlString(year));
    }
    return get_values;                                    
}
```

Comment: `IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array`  The only place in your code to get that exception is when accessing the `substrings[index]` .Make sure its length is `>=` 3

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Just a few tips on your next questions: please format your code better before posting it. The answers to your questions will serve other people, and it was really hard to read anything with that indentation.

Comment: Highligted the exception. So that anyone can understand what is the issue

Answer (score -2, accepted):

IndexOutOfRangeException occurs when you try to access an array index that does not exist.

By looking at your code, there are only two places where the problem could lie.

First, I can see that the collection is filled by looping on the results of that DAO_SignUp call:

```
List<DAO_SignUp> get_signUp_val = new List<DAO_SignUp>(DAO_SignUp.get_signUp(userid));   
foreach (var obj2 in get_signUp_val) (...)
```

We can then deduce that the problem could be that `DAO_SignUp.get_signUp(userid)` is not returning anything on the server, thus the collection returned by the function `get_signUp_values()` would have no elements and when trying to access the resulting index of that function, the error is raised.
As you said it is running just fine on localhost, you should then check the configurations on that DAO_SignUp. If it connects to a Database, check if it has data, and if the connection string points to the correct database.

The other option is, as pointed in the comments by L.B, the array returned by the `Regex.Split` inside the loop:

```
string[] substrings = Regex.Split(dob, patren);
string day = substrings[0];
string month = substrings[1];
string year = substrings[2];
```

If the `Regex.Split` returns nothing, that error will be raised. In this case, check for the Length of `substrings` before accessing it's index.

Comment: Ok let check this i would responce if the problem solved

Comment: Thank you so much for responding my problem is solved isue was the database i was upload the dababase backup file which was added copies of it self i just delete the old backup file create new from sql server and upload error fixed. you were rite the page was not properly getting the values.

Comment: Hi @ghasif, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this, though.

Comment: Also, note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by
up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough
reputation to do so), and by accepting the most helpful answer to any
question you ask (which also gives you a small boost to your
reputation).
Please see the [About] page and also [How do I ask questions
here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Have fun!